# kubernetes cronjob executed many times

Tags: kubernetes, cron, schedule

this is my kubernetes CronJob definition:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-monitor
  namespace: cronjobs
  labels:
    app: job-monitor
spec:
  schedule: "15 */6 * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
            agentpool: streaming
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
            - name: job-monitor
              image: imageRepository:latest
              securityContext:
                capabilities:
                  add:
                    - NET_ADMIN
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: "2000m"
                  memory: "4000Mi"
                limits:
                  cpu: "3000m"
                  memory: "6000Mi"
```

It gets executed @minute 15 but it get executed more than once so every minute. One day I saw the alert comming every minute @2:15, 2:16, 2:16, 2:18, 2:20 The other day @2:15, 2:16, 2:17, 2:18, 2:21.

Why?

Comment: The restart policy says `restartPolicy: OnFailure`. So are you sure the alert is sent only after everything is completed by the cronjob ? Maybe it gets restarted more than once ? What about logs ? Are you capturing all the logs ? Every execution should be captured in  logs.

Comment: No, the answer was not useful and not correct to my questions/issue

Answer (score 0):

As I checked the above comments and Answer :

You want to run the Job every 6 hours starting at minute 15 of the hour during Mon-Sun. So per day it runs 4 times.

If it starts from 0:15 min, 6:15 min, 12:15 min, 18:15 min again it repeats the same for the next day..

Syntax is :

```
15 */6 * * 1-7
```

**Output** :

I have tried the above  cron job syntax and it's working fine.

[image]

*If you find any errors let me know*.

Comment: @Dariusz :  I have posted an exact answer that answers what you are looking for. Verify it, if u find any errors let me know.

Comment: No, the answer was not useful and not correct to my questions/issue.

Comment: As per question above cron job schedule is correct but Can I know the reason why it's not correct have you tried with the above cron job? if so kindly  Post the errors.

Comment: Read the question again please

Comment: The question is: Why? Why does it get executed more than once? The answer is because the kubernetes cronjob deployment configuration was not correct and not the cronjob schedule itself.

Answer (score -1):

### Edited Answer Below:

Each line of a crontab file represents a job, and looks like this:

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * <command to execute>
```

For example, the following clears the Apache error log at one minute past midnight (00:01) every day,

```
1 0 * * * printf "" > /var/log/apache/error_log
```

On some systems it is also possible to specify */n to run for every n-th interval of time. Also, specifying multiple specific time intervals can be done with commas (e.g., 1,2,3). The below would output "hello world" to the command line every 5th minute of every first, second and third hour.

`*/5 1,2,3 * * * echo hello world`.

Comma ( , )
Commas are used to separate items of a list. For example, using "MON,WED,FRI" in the 5th field (day of week) means Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

For your concern, you want to run cron job for every 15 min in a week, Syntax should be below like this:

EX:

```
*/15 * * * “MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI”
```

Please let me know if you are still getting error.

Comment: what? my schedule is "15 */6 * * *"

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki I have edited my answer in the answer section this might solves your concern, try once if you face any errors let me know.

Comment: I do not want to run the job every 15 min Mon-Fri. I want to run it every 6 hours starting at minute 15 of the hour during Mon-Sun